# How to store SQLITE timestamp as string in Android Room db

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room, android-jetpack

I have a sqlite database.db file  from which I'm constructing the initial db for the app with `createFromAsset('database.db')`. It has a table which has a column of type timestamp. And I've created a room entity (table) and for the same column I've kept it's type as String.
But after running the application it's throwing `IllegalStateException` because it expected it to be String but found it as timestamp.
How to resolve this problem??

Comment: What is the format of the timestamps that you store in the database?

Comment: ISO8601 Format @forpas Does it matter??

Comment: Then the data type of the column should be TEXT.

Comment: Yes, But in my backend project that field is timestamp. @forpas

Comment: So I was just exporting .db file from my backend and then importing it in android.